# ReactJS data flow with deep hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, data-binding, reactjs, flux

I'm exploring ReactJS and trying to get a grasp of the core concepts. I started piecing a prototype of an application I am working on that has the following hierarchy of

- Customer

  - Locations

    - Addresses
    - Contacts

The page I am working on would be an input form for a Customer and all of its related children. Each of these sections would have some text inputs to house data, so they seemed like a natural place to house a hierarchy of components.

From everything I have read about ReactJS, if you are going to manage state, you should do so in the common ancestor of all the controls. This means that any changes in the child should bubble the event up to the keeper of the state to handle changes. This should then update the state and any changes will be re-rendered. This makes sense in simple scenarios, but that brings me to my slightly more complicated hierarchy.

- If a change happens down in one of the many Addresses, am I supposed to bubble up that event to the location then to the Customer?
- If so, what is the best way to tell state which specific address changed?
- If you have to call up through each level of the hierarchy, wouldn't that make a lot of extra boilerplate to propagate a simple change?
- Should I be attaching to the onChange event on each text box, or should I wait until I submit the form to gather the data?

React talks about ReactLink (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) as a way to manage more complex data binding, but doesn't give a great example of how to manage it with a larger hierarchy. Also, it states that most application shouldn't need this. Well, this application really isn't complicated, just a couple nested controls with shared state. This is where React is supposed to shine, so I wouldn't think to immediately jump to the edge case solutions.

Comment: I think the piece you are missing is how to manipulate state.  In your example, the data would be managed in Customer, then passed down via props to your other components.  Likewise, you can create your functions to handle events which change state in Customer, then pass them down as callbacks via props.  Then the child components can use the callback to change state when an event occurs.

Comment: @Mark That is how I understood it as well, but as soon as you get past one level deep, you are sending callbacks through several layers of components. So Location would have to pass down a callback that has nothing to do with its behavior. Is this how React wants you to handle it? If so that's fine, it just feels a bit clunky for how elegant other aspects of React are.

Comment: Yes, you would have to pass down the callbacks through several layers of components.  Since you are using JSX, one elegant way to handle this is using the JSX spread attribute (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html), which allows you to pass down all props received using `{...this.props}`.  This is very helpful when passing down many props through multiple layers of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced the same puzzle - the React docs are not very complete in this area. This is one way I found to work:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            p: 'Hello World',
            q: 'Click me if I\'m pink!',
            r: 'A'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='parent'>
                <p>
                    <h3>Parent</h3>
                    <tt>
                        p: {this.state.p}<br />
                        q: {this.state.q}<br />
                        r: {this.state.r}
                    </tt>
                </p>

                <Child q = {this.linkState('q')}
                       p = {this.linkState('p')}
                       r = {this.linkState('r')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Child = React.createClass({
    clicked: function() {
        this.props.q.requestChange("Thank you :)");
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='child'>
                <h3>Child</h3>

                <p>
                    <input valueLink={this.props.p} />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <tt onClick={this.clicked}>
                        {this.props.q.value}
                    </tt>
                </p>

                <select valueLink={this.props.r}>
                    <option value={'A'}>A</option>
                    <option value={'B'}>B</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Parent />, document.body)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cachvico/p81s75x5/

If anyone has any improvements I'd be glad to hear them!

Comment: jsfiddle gives some errors: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
jsfiddle-integration.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Still working for me in regular Chrome 43.0.2357.130 and Firefox 38.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this a lot as side effect of making component as little as possible.

I had to pass down onChange to 4-5 levels down the hierarchy because at the actual state is at the top most level (container).

Here's an example:

```js
<ProjectContainer>
  <ProjectComponent onProjectChange onProjectTaskChange onCommentChange>
    <ProjectTasksComponent onProjectTaskChange onCommentChange>
      <ProjectTaskComponent onProjectTaskChange onCommentChange>
        <ProjectTaskCommentsComponent onCommentChange>
          <ProjectTaskCommentComponent onCommentChange>
```

Comment: As I have learned as I have gotten used to the component structure of React as well as Angular 2, this is the default way to handle things. If you want to avoid this type of pattern, you either can look at a pattern like Flux, or a library like Redux to centralize state changes that complete the unidirectional flow of data.